# Can't import models in tasks.py with Celery + Django

Tags: python, django, celery, python-import

I want to create a background task to update a record on a specific date. I'm using Django and Celery with RabbitMQ.

I've managed to get the task called when the model is saved with this dummy task function:

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://localhost//')


@app.task(name='news.tasks.update_news_status')
def update_news_status(news_id):
    # (I pass the news id and return it, nothing complicated about it)
    return news_id
```

this task is called from my save() method in my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from celery import current_app


class News(models.model):
    (...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        current_app.send_task('news.tasks.update_news_status', args=(self.id,))

        super(News, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thing is **I want to import my News model in tasks.py** but if I try to like this:

`from .models import News`

I get this error :

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must
>   either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

This is how mi **celery.py** looks like

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
import os
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
app = Celery('myapp')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

I have already tried this:

1. [can't import django model into celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755583/cant-import-django-model-into-celery-task)
2. I have tried to make the import inside the task method [Django and Celery, AppRegisteredNotReady exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876482/django-and-celery-appregisterednotready-exception)
3. I have also tried this [Celery - importing models in tasks.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212082/celery-importing-models-in-tasks-py/50314466)
4. I also tried to create a utils.py and import it and was not possible.

and ran into different errors but **in the end I'm not able to import any module in tasks.py**

There might be something wrong with my config but I can't see the error, I followed the steps in [The Celery Docs: First steps with Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Also, my project structure looks like this:

```
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
├── ├── celery.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── news
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
├── manage.py
```

I'm executing the worker from `myapp` directory like this:

`celery -A news.tasks worker --loglevel=info`

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for your help!

lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS

**EDIT**

After making the changes suggested in comments:
Add this to celery.py 
`app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)`

and import inside method: tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://localhost//')


@app.task(name='news.tasks.update_news_status')
def update_news_status(news_id):
    from .models import News
    return news_id
```

I get the following error:

```
[2018-07-20 12:24:29,337: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task news.tasks.update_news_status[87f9ec92-c260-4ee9-a3bc-5f684c819f79] raised unexpected: ValueError('Attempted relative import in non-package',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/carla/Develop/App/backend/myapp-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/carla/Develop/App/backend/myapp-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/carla/Develop/App/backend/news/tasks.py", line 12, in update_news_status
    from .models import News
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: can you use this app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS) what is celery version>>>???

Comment: Hi @HemanthSP adding that did not work. Celery version is 4.2.1

Comment: can you try celery -A news worker -l info, your code is working fine with redis. and try move every code in task.py to celery.py and check once again

Comment: the code shown here works, what I can't achieve is to import News model into tasks.py @HemanthSP

Comment: your error from django  or celery terminal?

Comment: you need to show full error trace

Comment: I added an Edit with the new error @HemanthSP the error is in celery terminal

Comment: @ParaM I added a new error with the error trace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so for anyone struggling with this... turns out my celery.py wasn't reading env variables from the settings.

After a week and lots of research I realised that **Celery is not a process of Django but a process running outside of it** (duh), so when I tried to load the settings they were loaded but then I wasn't able to access the env variables I have defined in my .env ( I use the dotenv library). **Celery was trying to look up for the env variables in my .bash_profile** (of course)

So in the end my solution was to create a helper module in the same directory where my `celery.py` is defined, called `load_env.py` with the following

```
from os.path import dirname, join
import dotenv


def load_env():
    "Get the path to the .env file and load it."
    project_dir = dirname(dirname(__file__))
    dotenv.read_dotenv(join(project_dir, '.env'))
```

and then on my **celery.py** (note the last import and first instruction)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
import os
from .load_env import load_env

load_env()

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

app = Celery('myapp')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.

app.config_from_object('myapp.settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

after the call to `load_env()` env variables are loaded and the celery worker has access to them. By doing this **I am now able to access other modules from my tasks.py**, which was my main problem.

Credits to [this guys (Caktus Consulting Group)](https://github.com/caktus) and their [django-project-template](https://github.com/caktus/django-project-template) because if it wasn't for them I wouldn't find the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. its working in 3.1 celery, **import should happen inside save method and after super()**

```
from django.db import models



class News(models.model):
    (...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        (...)
        super(News, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        from task import update_news_status
        update_news_status.apply_async((self.id,)) #apply_async or delay
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is not on models.py its on tasks.py that I need to import the News model

Comment: i know error coming like that only , did you tried my solution ?

Comment: Yes but I have already called tasks in models.py there is no problem there. The problem is the other way around, from models import News inside tasks.py is not possible so I can't do anything on the task

Comment: I import lot of model in my tasks.py and its working like a charm for me

Answer (score 0):

Here what i would do (Django 1.11 and celery 4.2), you have a problem in your celery config and you try to re-declare the Celery instance :

**tasks.py**

```
from myapp.celery import app # would contain what you need :)
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task(name='news.tasks.update_news_status')
def update_news_status(news_id):
    # (I pass the news id and return it, nothing complicated about it)
    return news_id
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
app = Celery('myapp', backend='rpc://', broker=BROKER_URL) # your config here
app.config_from_object('django.myapp:settings', namespace='CELERY') # change here
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class News(models.model):
    (...)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(News, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        from news.tasks import update_news_status
        update_news_status.delay(self.id) # change here
```

And launch it with `celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=info` because your app is defined in myapp.celery so -A parameter need to be the app where the conf is declared